# Fixed height background image over entire width

Tags: html, css, image, background

Right now I am using following code to have an image scaled to the entire width and height of the screen. What I actually am trying to accomplish is that the image itself keeps its original height, but that it cuts off the sides of the image if a user scales down his browser. Anybody who can help me out?

```
html{
    background: url(jup.png) no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='jup.png',     sizingMethod='scale');
    -ms-filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='jup.png', sizingMethod='scale');
}
```

Comment: jsfiddle. and I do not see anything wrong with your code.. it should give you what you want!

Comment: the code I am using right now is scaling the image over the full height of the screen, not a fixed height (= the height of the original image, lets say 500px)...

Comment: how about using `max-height;` and `max-width` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use values in background-size:

```
background-size:500px auto;
```

Comment: or background-size:100% auto;

Comment: small extra question, is there also a way to specify a min width, so it start scrolling then? I tried min-width but that doesn't work apparantly..

Comment: min-width wouldn't have any effect on background images. Can you explain a little clearer what the intended goal is?The only way I could think of, with what I think the goal is, would be to toggle a class depending on the page width or page ratio. Or use media queries to change the css dependent on width.

Comment: I want to make it that when a user would reduce it to let say 1000px witdh, the backgroundimage stops reducing in width and the text etc won't 'glide' anymore, a scroll bar (horizontally) has to appear then.

Comment: @media only screen and (max-width : 1000px) {
  selector { background-size: auto; }
}

Comment: Just in case, this not works with svg backgrounds, at least in Chrome. The browser keeps the ratio and ignores the fixed height.